# Block error: post_taxs_obj is not a valid property of Object

Tags: block-editor

One of our blocks has stopped working, I understand its probably due to the 'post_taxs_obj' not being included in the PHP register_block_type attributes but I'm not sure how to resolve this - can anyone please advise? (I'm not a dev, just trying to jump in and fix this so any help would be much appreciated):

Error:

```
{"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Invalid parameter(s): attributes","data":{"status":400,"params":{"attributes":"post_taxs_obj is not a valid property of Object."},"details":{"attributes":{"code":"rest_additional_properties_forbidden","message":"post_taxs_obj is not a valid property of Object.","data":null}}}}
```

Here's the PHP:

```
register_block_type( 'performancein/article-listing',
        array(
            'render_callback' => 'performancein_article_listing_callback',
            'attributes'      => [
                'post_type'            => [
                    'default' => '',
                    'type'    => 'string'
                ],
                'post_taxs'            => [
                    'default' => '',
                    'type'    => 'string'
                ],
                'post_category'        => [
                    'default' => '',
                    'type'    => 'string'
                ],
                'number_of_post'       => [
                    'default' => '0',
                    'type'    => 'number'
                ],
                'category_description' => [
                    'default' => false,
                    'type'    => 'bool'
                ],
                'exclude_post'         => [
                    'default' => '',
                    'type'    => 'string'
                ],

            ]
        )
    );
```

And the JS:

```
registerBlockType('performancein/article-listing', {
  title: 'Article Listing',
  icon: ArticleIcon,
  category: 'performancein',
  keywords: [__('ArticleFilter'), __('gutenberg'), __('performancein')],
  description: __( 'It showcase article listing ' ),
  example: {
    attributes: {
      caption: __( 'Article Listing' ),
    },
  },
  attributes: {

    number_of_post: {
      type: 'number',
      default: '0',
    },
    post_type: {
      default: '',
      type: 'string',
    },
    post_type_obj: {
      type: 'json',
    },
    post_taxs: {
      default: '',
      type: 'string',
    },
    post_taxs_obj: {
      default: [{label: '--Select Taxonomy--', value: ''}],
      type: 'json',
    },
    post_category: {
      default: '',
      type: 'string',
    },
    post_category_obj: {
      default: [{label: '--Select Category--', value: ''}],
      type: 'json',
    },
    category_description: {
      default: false,
      type: 'boolean',
    },
    exclude_post: {type: 'string'},
    design_option: {
      type: 'string',
      default: '',
    },
  },
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the fix Tom, solution was simply to follow his guidance with the format of:

```
'post_type_obj'        => [
                    'default' => '',
                    'type'    => 'json'
                ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP registers a block with **6 attributes**.

Your JS registers a block with **10 attributes**.

They ***must*** match, it is non-negotiable. You can't claim one thing in PHP then say another in javascript. Your code lied to one of the APIs.

You can either:

- add the missing attributes to PHP
- or remove the extra attributes from javascript

Most likely the first one.

As an aside, have you considered using server side registration with a `block.json` and sidestepping the problem completely? Then your JS registration would only need 3 things, the blocks name and its edit/save components, everything else would be pulled automatically from `block.json`, and WP would inline all that data and use it automatically. It would even enqueue the frontend and editor scripts for you.

Comment: Thanks Tom – I couldn't paste a code sample properly here in a comment so I've added an answer below. Would you mind casting your eye over it please!? Thanks again

Comment: Thanks Tom, I've updated the original question as you requested. Apologies for getting that wrong